# HMAC-SHA1 Swift 3 - 403 Forbidden

Tags: ios, swift, digital-signature, hmac, kong

I'm trying to perform an HMAC-SHA1 signature from Swift 3 to a kong server which inreturn redirects to Twitter host( To enable HMAC on Kong - followed https://getkong.org/plugins/hmac-authentication/ )

I use the same secret key, username in my swift. Performing HMAC-SHA1 on current date with the secret key and sending request to http://localhost:8000/@foo

Swift 3 code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let date = Date()
    let currentDateF = DateFormatter()
    let localeF = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let tzone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    currentDateF.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
    currentDateF.timeZone = tzone
    currentDateF.locale = localeF
    let currentDate = currentDateF.string(from: date)
    let dat = "date: \(currentDate)"
    let username = "bar"
    let hmacResult: String = dat.getHmac(algorithm: .SHA1, key: "foo")
    HTTPrequest(Datestr: currentDate, hmacAuth: hmacResult, username: username)
}

func HTTPrequest(Datestr: String, hmacAuth: String, username: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/@foo")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.addValue(Datestr, forHTTPHeaderField: "date")
    request.addValue("twitter.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    request.setValue("hmac username='\(username)', algorithm='hmac-sha1', headers='date', signature='\(hmacAuth)'", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        print("DATA RETURNED: \(data!)")
        let str = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print("VALUE: \(str!)")
        print("RESPONSE: \(response!)")
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}


enum hmacAlgo {
    case SHA1
    func  toHMACAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

extension String  {
    func getHmac(algorithm: hmacAlgo, key: String) -> String {
        let stringData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
        let keyData = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
        CCHmac(algorithm.toHMACAlgorithm(), keyData!, Int(strlen(keyData!)), stringData!, Int(strlen(stringData!)), &result)
        let hmacData: NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
        let hmacb64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength76Characters)
        return hmacb64
    }
}
```

But I get 403 Status Code - Forbidden with message stating HMAC signature cannot be verified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

```
request.setValue("hmac username=\"\(username)\", algorithm=\"hmac-sha1\", headers=\"date\", signature=\"\(hmacAuth)\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

I just wrapped the strings in the authorization header with double quotes and sent the request.
Thank you.